# How can I scale the gap between x-axis ticks which are dates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a bar graph which has datetimes on the x-axis. How can I add gaps between x-ticks with respect to the timedelta between each neighbour ticks? The solution does not have to be a bargraph, I can use any kind of graph which satisfies my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these kind of problems you may set x axis as date field. This will fill in na dates and leave gaps accordingly which is helpful to analyze time series and things like monthly spending and it's quite easy to do. Following code snipper should help.

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, y, width=10)
ax.xaxis_date()

plt.show()
```